# How to pass function with super() when creating class dynamically?

Tags: python, class

Let's say I have this code:

```py
class StaticParent:
  def _print(self):
    print("I'm StaticParent")

class StaticChild(StaticParent):
  def _print(self):
    print('StaticChild saying: ')
    super()._print()

def _parent_print_proto(self):
  print("I'm DynamicParent")

def _child_print_proto(self):
  print('DynamicChild saying: ')
  super()._print()

DynamicParent = type('DynamicParent', tuple([]), {"_print": _parent_print_proto})

DynamicChild = type('DynamicChild', (DynamicParent,), {"_print": _child_print_proto})

sc = StaticChild()
sc._print()

dc = DynamicChild()
dc._print()
```

And it's output is:

```
StaticChild saying:
I'm StaticParent
DynamicChild saying:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 28, in <module>
    dc._print()
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 17, in _child_print_proto
    super()._print()
RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found
```

#### So question is how to create prototype method for many classes that calling `super()`?

<sub>PS I tried to implement method with lambda but it is also not working:</sub>

```
DynamicChildWithLambda = type('DynamicChild', (DynamicParent,), {"_print": lambda self : print('Lambda saying: ', super()._print())})
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 30, in <module>
    dcwl._print()
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    DynamicChildWithLambda = type('DynamicChild', (DynamicParent,), {"_print": lambda self : print('Lambda saying: ', super()._print())})
RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found
```

<sub>PS2 Also I tried this way:</sub>

```py
class StaticParent:

  def _print(self):
    print("I'm StaticParent")

def _child_print_proto(self):
  print('DynamicChild saying: ')
  super(StaticParent, self)._print()

DynamicChild = type('DynamicChild', (StaticParent,), {"_print": _child_print_proto})

dc = DynamicChild()
dc._print()
```

```
DynamicChild saying:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 13, in <module>
    dc._print()
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 8, in _child_print_proto
    super(StaticParent, self)._print()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_print'
```

Comment: Probably worth taking a peak at [`super()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) =>  `The zero argument form only works inside a class definition`

Comment: @Mark Yep. The reason is surely clear but how to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods defined within a class get a fake closure scope that automatically provides the class it was defined in to no-arg `super()`. When defined outside a class, it can't do this (because clearly no class is being defined at the time you define the method). But you can still make a closure the old-fashioned way, by actually writing a closure function that you manually define `__class__` appropriately in:

```python
class StaticParent:
  def _print(self):
    print("I'm StaticParent")

class StaticChild(StaticParent):
  def _print(self):
    print('StaticChild saying: ')
    super()._print()

def _parent_print_proto(self):
    print("I'm DynamicParent")

# Nesting allows us to make the inner function have an appropriate __class__
# defined for use by no-arg super
def _make_child_print_proto(cls):
  __class__ = cls
  def _child_print_proto(self):
    print('DynamicChild saying: ')
    super()._print()
  return _child_print_proto

DynamicParent = type('DynamicParent', tuple([]), {"_print": _parent_print_proto})

DynamicChild = type('DynamicChild', (DynamicParent,), {})
# Need DynamicChild to exist to use it as __class__, bind after creation
DynamicChild._print = _make_child_print_proto(DynamicChild)

sc = StaticChild()
sc._print()

dc = DynamicChild()
dc._print()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJBS8QwEIXv/RVDPbSB4sVbwZNevCyCR5EQ06kbbNOSTMEi/vaaJnU3cXfRSykv8755M8k4037QN8siO2EtPJEgJR@FQU11BtBgC3w0SlNpsWvZqgEEIX8o@sSQsyyLMXd71TVlXMH@YhaRE6yYlX6roWC@wk4jmpJdb17XLJA8OYjuO9BwIer9rEUfZ/X2Xrwjl2u/BCE76wmc@4k4h1tw2k/8U8PpKFu//80CYJAmo8@gsyxJ7oLQPOKBH9SiAprGDsvnF1bBZx4AeX1uP1/sgAzhfhG96IBl0qFauc56BTvEBhIADYAfytL6M1kERSDscXcVvCrdgGgJDUiD7ooHnUTYFuGSXLqQuNrlt9LVxs@MOSl@Gut57HFicyxYlm8)

Yes, it's hacky and awful. In real code, I'd just use the less common explicit two-arg `super`:

```python
def _child_print_proto(self):
  print('DynamicChild saying: ')
  super(DynamicChild, self)._print()
```

That's all `super()` does anyway; Python hides the class it was defined in in closure scope as `__class__`, `super()` pulls it and the first positional argument, assumed to be `self`, and implicitly does the same thing the two-arg form did explicitly.

To be clear: **You *cannot* pass `self.__class__` manually as the first argument to two-arg `super()`, to simulate the `__class__` that is bound in closure scope.** It appears to work, and it does work, until you actually make a child of the class with that method and try to call the method on it (and the whole point of `super()` is you might have an arbitrarily complex class hierarchy to navigate; you can't just say "Oh, but my class is special enough to never be subclassed again"). If you do something as simple as adding:

```python
class DynamicGrandChild(DynamicChild):
    pass

dgc = DynamicGrandChild()
dgc._print()
```

to the `self.__class__`-using code from [Epsi95's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71879787/364696), you're going to see:

```
StaticChild saying: 
I'm StaticParent
DynamicChild saying: 
I'm DynamicParent
DynamicChild saying: 
DynamicChild saying: 
DynamicChild saying: 
DynamicChild saying: 
DynamicChild saying: 
DynamicChild saying: 
DynamicChild saying: 
DynamicChild saying: 
... repeats a thousand times or so ...
DynamicChild saying: 
DynamicChild saying: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".code.tio", line 31, in <module>
    dgc._print()
  File ".code.tio", line 15, in _child_print_proto
    super(self.__class__, self)._print()
  File ".code.tio", line 15, in _child_print_proto
    super(self.__class__, self)._print()
  File ".code.tio", line 15, in _child_print_proto
    super(self.__class__, self)._print()
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
  File ".code.tio", line 14, in _child_print_proto
    print('DynamicChild saying: ')
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

`super()` is used when you're designing for inheritance. `super(self.__class__, self)` is used only when you're *sabotaging* inheritance. The only safe ways to do this involve some sort of static linkage to the class (the one that the method will be attached to, *not* the run time type of whatever instance it is called with), and my two solutions above are the two reasonable ways to do this (there's only one other option really, which is making the closure, and still passing the class and `self` explicitly, e.g. instead of defining `__class__`, just use `super(cls, self)` to explicitly use a closure variable; not sufficiently distinct, and kinda the worst of both worlds).

---

So, I said "there's three ways", but in fact there is a *slightly* nicer (but also less portable, because the API for `types.FunctionType` has changed over time, even though closures defined normally haven't) solution, which lets you make a utility function to bind arbitrary functions to arbitrary classes, instead of requiring you to wrap each such function in a closure-maker. And that's to literally rebuild the function as a closure directly:

```python
import types

# Define function normally, with super(). The function can't actually be used as is though
def _child_print_proto(self):
  print('DynamicChild saying: ')
  super()._print()

# Utility function binding arbitrary function to arbitrary class
def bind_to_class(cls, func):
  # This translates as:
  # Make a new function using the same code object as the passed function,
  # but tell it it has one closure scoped variable named __class__, and
  # provide the class as the value to associate with it.
  # This requires Python 3.8 or later (code objects didn't have a replace method
  # until then, so doing this would be even uglier than it already is)
  return types.FunctionType(func.__code__.replace(co_freevars=('__class__',)), func.__globals__, closure=(types.CellType(cls),))

DynamicParent = type('DynamicParent', tuple([]), {"_print": _parent_print_proto})

DynamicChild = type('DynamicChild', (DynamicParent,), {})
# Rebind the function to a new function that believes it was defined in DynamicChild
DynamicChild._print = bind_to_class(DynamicChild, _child_print_proto)
```

Like I said, it's super-ugly and would need rewrites pre-3.8, but it does have the mild advantage of allowing you to use `bind_to_class` with arbitrary `super()` using functions to bind them to arbitrary classes. I still think manually calling two-arg `super` is the safe/obvious way to go, but now you've got all the options.

Comment: Yeah looking cool and tricky, but second answer from `Epsi95` is simple and easy readable. And about `I'd just use the less common explicit two-arg` → You can see my second PS in question. Looks like this way is not working too

Comment: @rzlvmp: It's simple, easy to read, and *100% wrong* (using `self.__class__` as an argument to `super()` is *never* okay, because it means any subclass of the class that uses it will recurse infinitely if you call that method on it), but you do you. :-)

Comment: @rzlvmp: I've added an explanation to my answer as to why you don't do this, *ever*, and what happens if you do.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have tried to fixed it by `super(self.__class__.mro()[-3], self)._print()` by which it will always pick the right class

Comment: @Epsi95: Unless there's multiple inheritance going on, in which case you might be in a different part of the MRO than you expect (the whole reason `super()` exists is to support otherwise nigh impossible to resolve issues with multiple inheritance; the MRO is a result of trying to linearize the non-linear inheritance hierarchy involve in multiple inheritance). Trust me when I say that there is no safe way to make `self.__class__`-based solutions work unless you can *guarantee* no one will ever extend your class hierarchy, ever.

Comment: Yes I also thought that, in complex inheritance, it will not be that simple, like if `DynamicParent` is inheriting from something etc